# Issue with Angular 2 routing: feature module doesn't load in the right place

Tags: angular, routes

In my Angular 2 app, I am trying to reproduce this navigation structure:

[image]

I have one big router outlet in my root application component, inside which I'm either loading my marketing website, or my application when the user logs in. 
So once the user is logged in `MyComponent` (in maroon) is loaded into the red router outlet and it has a navigation bar (`MyHeader`, in black and grey), and its own router outlet (in blue). When I click Home in the navigation bar, it loads a dashboard component into the blue router outlet and everything looks fine. But when I click the Benefits link, I want it to load the `BenefitsComponent` (in orange and yellow) from the `BenefitsModule` into the blue router-outlet. But instead, it seems to load it into the red router-outlet, the one from `AppComponent` instead, since the navigation bar from `MyComponent`disappears.

I have created a [simplified version of my project on Github](https://github.com/sarbogast/ng2-routing-example).

There is obviously something I am missing. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?

EDIT: Just to add a bit of context, I'm trying to modify my routing structure from something lazy loading the benefits module. Originally I lazy loaded every module but it's not really useful here as the benefits section should be loaded with the logged in section of my app. Originally, I had this with lazy loading:

- in `my.module.ts` I had no mention of `BenefitsModule` since it was lazy-loaded
- in `my-routing.module.ts`I had an additional line to load the module:

  { path: 'benefits', loadChildren: 'app/my/benefits/benefits.module#BenefitsModule', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]}
- and in `benefits-routing.module.ts` I had no mention of the `benefits`path since it was present in `my-routing.module.ts`

And this worked perfectly. As you can see for yourself in [the `lazy-loading` branch of my repository](https://github.com/sarbogast/ng2-routing-example/tree/lazy-loading). So I guess my question is how to go from this lazy-loading situation to the eager loading one without losing the navigation structure I had.

EDIT 2: Using `activate` event on each router outlet, I just confirmed that when using lazy-loading, my benefits component is loaded into the router-outlet in MyComponent but without lazy loading, it is loaded into the root AppComponent router outlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I investigated your problem. The thing is that you wanted the *BenefitsComponent* to load inside *MyComponent*. But how can he do that if it's not a child of *MyComponent*? So in order to fix that you need to add it to the children list like you do when lazy loading. The only thing is, you don't want lazy loading here. But since RC6 (and thus also the release) of the Router, you can just pass down a function that returns a module. This makes switching to lazy loading quite simple as well, just remove the import and use a string literal to point to the module.

I added a PR to your GitHub repository to show you how it works. https://github.com/sarbogast/ng2-routing-example/pull/1